# Replicating "Unchecked chrome.runtime.lastError" Warning

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, error-handling

I need to replicate chrome.runtime.lastError functionality. How can I trigger the warning that fires when chrome.runtime.lastError is not caught in a custom function?

```js
if(self.chrome == null) {
 self.chrome = { runtime: { } }
}

chrome.test = function(option, callback) {
 if(option) {
  callback("done")
 } else {
  chrome.runtime.lastError = { message: "Needs something." }
  callback()
  chrome.runtime.lastError = undefined
} }

chrome.test(false, function(result) {
 console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and overwriting chrome.runtime.

```js
if(self.chrome == null) {
 self.chrome = { runtime: { } }
}

chrome.test = function(option, callback) {
 if(option) {
  callback("done")
 } else {
  let error = "Needs something."
  let unchecked = true
  chrome.oldruntime = chrome.runtime
  chrome.runtime = new Proxy(chrome.runtime, {
   get(target, key) {
    if(key == "lastError") {
     unchecked = false
     return({ message: error })
    } else {
     return(target[key])
  } } })
  callback()
  chrome.runtime = chrome.oldruntime
  if(unchecked) {
   console.error("Unchecked runtime.lastError while running chrome.test: " + error)
} } }

chrome.test(false, function(result) {
  console.log(result)
})
```